# how to watch vr videos in my PC?

Tags: video, vlc-media-player

I have seen in some films sites that they have options to download videos as the following:

[image]

Actually I do not have an Oculus drift or any hardware to watch those videos, but only my PC. Also, I would not like to use something like the Google Cardboard on a Smartphone because it is not so comfortable. The problem is that when I open a downloaded vr video which is in mp4 format, for example using VLC, the screen appears divided in two and I cannot control the movement of the camera. I have tried other tools such as KMPlayer, but it does not allow to move or to zoom by using the mouse and the keyboard configuration is fixed. I manage to get an old version of the GoPro Player, which is not longer supported, and it works so so, mainly because the image appears immediately zoomed out.

I was wondering if there is a way to see the vr videos using a browser, for example when I open the embedded videos of a film page using Chrome I can interact freely. My question is if there is a way to open a downloaded vr film using Chrome or if there are some extensions to VLC to watch this kind of videos, with the same functionality as when one uses the browser to watch an embedded web page film.

Thanks

Comment: What's the point in having VR content with no way to view it? VR needs two eyes… two pictures, one for each eye. If all you can do is watch them side by side on your computer monitor, there is literally no point in wasting bandwidth on the second image. Aside from that, I assume all that VR content relies on movement input from the applicable headset - no headset, no movement.

Comment: @Tetsujin thank for your comment, but from example in Google Chrome one can make the camera move within the browser; the problem is that it only works in streamming.